# python dict attribute and items

Tags: python, dictionary

In following python code, what is the difference between dict.setitem and 
setattr ?

when I comment the setattr statement, I cannot run g.abcd. But if I keep the
setattr statement,
I can run both g.abcd and g['abcd'], which return the same  value 300

`id(g.abcd) and id(g['abcd'])` returns the same value.

I am confused: dict.setitem should insert a hash  pair into the 
hash table. setattr should add an extra attributes (or field, or member) to 
class dict. so they seem to be different thing. Therefore I think it is 
expected that eliminating setattr will fail g.abcd.

**But I don't understand 
why id() returns the same value for g.abcd and g['abcd'], why they refer to 
the same thing/location in the memory?**

thx

```
class T(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)   #  <-------  dict.setitem
        setattr(self, key, value)                 #  <-------- setattr


g=T()
g.__setitem__('abcd', 300)
```

---

```
>>> id(g.abcd)

147169236

>>> id(g['abcd'])

147169236
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you store the same object in both cases. So, when you retrieve it, you are getting the same object regardless of which way you get it. How could it be any other way?

Comment: yes,I set the two dict's (one is g.__dict__ by setattr, the other one is g.__keys__ and g.__value__). But they are two different dict's. Therefore I expect id() returns different value for g['abcd'] and g.abcd. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Yes. The dictionaries are different, but they both have the same value stored in them. You didn't change `value` between your two assignments, so how could it not?

Comment: that is what confuses me. If it is two separate dict's, the hash-entries should be at different locations, therefore I expect id() returns different values, even the hash entries have the same content. You are suggesting that the two different dict's share the same entries? Is there any docs that explains what you mentinoed? thx

Comment: Oh, I see the source of your confusion. Dicts  (all containers, in fact) contain references to the objects they contain, they do not contain the objects themselves. Those are stored elsewhere. So when you assign your value into the dict, you are storing a reference to it, it does not make a copy of the object.

Comment: I think what you said is right, at least for my original case. But when I do an experiment like,   x={'a':20}   and y={'a':20}, id() actually returns different values for x and y. So, it seems to me sometimes we do have duplicates of entries, which is not the case in my original program.

Comment: `x` and `y` are in fact different objects. `x['a']` and `y['a']` are the same object, but that's an implementation detail (Python reuses small integer objects). However, if you defined `x` and then said `y = x` then `id(x)` and `id(y)` would be the same.